# Probability that a married worker is male.

Tags: probability

In a certain company, 40% of the employees are females. Suppose 60% of the male
workers are married and 40% of the female workers are married. What is the
probability that a married worker is male?

My proof:

$$A = {Female}$$

$$A^c = Male $$

$$B = Married$$

So, $$P(A^c) = 0.6$$

$$P(B/A^c) = 0.6 * 0.6 = 0.36$$
I believe this means the probability of randomly picking a married male. So, I do not know if this is the answer or I keep going:

$$P(A) = 0.4$$
$$P(B/A) = 0.4 * 0.4 = 0.16$$
So, $$P((B/A^c) ∪ (B/A)) = ((B/A^c)  + (B/A)) -((B/A^c)(B/A)) $$
$$(0.52) - (0.0576) = 0.4626 $$=PROBABILITY OF PICKING A RANDOM MARRIED EMPLOYEE AT RANDOM

So, $$P(A^c ∩ ((B/A^c) ∪ (B/A))) = 0.6 * 0.4626 = .2744$$

Which is my final answer, but I am very confused by this question since it seems like a small probability and apparently 60% of workers are male and 60% of those male workers are married

Comment: You have to calculate the probability that a person is male,**given that he/she is married**. Hence, you have to calculate $P(A^c | B)$. You have done the opposite.

Comment: So it would still be 0.6 * 0.6 , so the final answer comes out to be .36?

Comment: Yes. The answer is the same, but that is a coincidence, because $P(B)=P(A^c)$, so it doesn't matter which one is in the denominator. You would have got a different answer if they were not the same.

Comment: OK, I see. So,  it would end up being 0.6 * 0.36 = 0.216 / 0.6 = 0.36, which would yield a totally different result if a different percent of males were married. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Just in case, try it with a different percent of married males. the difference is quite stark.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there are exactly $100$ employees at this company.  If $40\%$ of workers are female, then $40$ are female and $100 - 40 = 60$ are male.  If $40\%$ of these female workers are married, then there are $40(0.4) = 16$ married female workers and $40 - 16 = 24$ unmarried female workers.  If $60\%$ of the $60$ male workers are married, then there are $60(0.6) = 36$ married male workers, and $60 - 36 = 24$ unmarried male workers.  We summarize this in the following table:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} & \text{Female} & \text{Male} & \text{Total} \\ \hline \text{Married} & 16 & 36 & 52 \\ \hline \text{Unmarried} & 24 & 24 & 48 \\ \hline \text{Total} & 40 & 60 & 100 \end{array}$$
Therefore, among the $16 + 36 = 52$ married workers of either sex, $36$ are males, and if one married worker is chosen at random, the chance this person is male is simply $36/52 = 9/13 \approx 0.692308$.