# Calculating Probability using Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I'm trying to calculate using the bayes theorem the exercise below.

But Im confused.

In one company, 40% of the employees are women. Suppose 60% of men workers are married, and 40% of women workers are married. How likely is a married worker to be a man?

What is the correct answer? I found about 0.69.

36/52. that's right?

Comment: Yes, that answer looks good.

Comment: @lulu how can I use the Bayes Theorem? And I believe this is not the right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed:

$P(man|married) = \frac{P(married/man) \cdot P(man)}{P(married/man) \cdot P(man) + P(married/woman) \cdot P(woman)} = \frac{0.6 \cdot 0.6}{0.6 \cdot 0.6 + 0.4 \cdot 0.4}=\frac{9}{13}$

So you are right!

Comment: No, the law of the total probability is applied at your $\textrm{denominator}$. Bayes theorem is right and your application of it is right.

Comment: @callculus $9/13$ its not the right answer.

Comment: @DiogoBastos It is the right answer.

Comment: Thanks @callculus for pointing that out. Corrected!

Comment: Is it or is it not? :-) @callculus can you give more details? What's wrong with the solution?

Comment: @pendermath It is the right answer. That´s why I´ve voted for it and I love it. I´ve just replied to Diogo Bastos comment.

Comment: Ah ok. Then, to @Diogo Bastos, what is wrong, if anything?

Comment: @pendermath https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941655/probability-that-a-married-worker-is-male

Comment: The solution of question 1941655 is also $9/13$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Its a weird question guys.

Comment: @Laura But a nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with an example. Suppose there are $100$ employees. Then there are $60$ men, $0.6\cdot60=36$ of whom are married, and there are $40$ women, $0.4\cdot40=16$ of whom are married. There are then $36+16=52$ married workers, $36$ of whom are men, so the probability in question is ${36\over52}={9\over13}$.

Comment: Sure, it's just that @Laura wanted it solved using Bayes' Theorem